# Recovering from a WSOD related to hierarchical select module

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I was messing around with the hierarchical select module (trying to create an exposed filter that would use the hierarchical select interface) I got some strange AJAX related error and then tried to cancel out of what I was doing.  After doing so, when ever I try and edit this view I get the White Screen of Death. I went to MAMP server PHP log files and found this error:

> [02-Feb-2012 15:58:10] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _hierarchical_select_setup_js() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/hierarchical_select/modules/hs_taxonomy_views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc on line 26

Since I can't get back to my view I don't seem to have any way to remove this broken exposed filter.  Any way out or did I just lose this whole view?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1062278

Comment: Drupal 7, that link does seem to describe the same issue as ine but they didn't offer any solutions.

Comment: It seems that the functions causing problems have not yet been ported to 7.  When browsing through the code, hierarchical_select_common_add_views_js() seems to only be referenced in D6.

Comment: So is there no way to disable the part of the view I was trying to add, or since I can't get to the edit view screen is the view basically uneditable?

Comment: I think using a 'function_exists()' wrapper like @Jimajamma suggested in his answer would do the trick.  That error is only happening because the function does not exist.  function_exists will not fix the problem, but it will likely prevent the WSOD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _hierarchical_select_setup_js() function is defined in the hierarchical_select.module so this is one of those "it should work" situations.  Since it isn't, a quick workaround would be to copy it out of there and into, oh, say, your template.php file, wrapped in a "if !function_exists()" so it doesn't WSOD when it does :)

Comment: Hmm, the method hierarchical_select_setup_js is actually not defined in my hierarchical_select.module, could this be part of the problem?  I tried downloading the development release and same deal, same error.

Comment: that would certainly be a/the problem :)  I am assuming now you are using d7, and sure enough, the only references to that function are in that inc file.  Sounds like a bug in the module to me.  Try just commenting it out to get your view back but no clues on how to make it right

Comment: Ah okay you were right, but now I get another error: [02-Feb-2012 18:51:37] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function hierarchical_select_common_add_views_js() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/all/modules/custom/hierarchical_select/modules/hs_taxonomy_views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc on line 30

Comment: Hopefully at some point the error will stop and I will get to a point where the WSOD stops.  If not, is there no other recourse but to recreate the view?

Comment: sounds like something to look into on the issue queue for the module on drupal.org at this point